# libgdx AssetManager fails to load resourse on html5 only

Tags: java, html, gwt, libgdx

I have a libgdx project that uses AssetManager to load the resources like so:

```
    for (FileHandle f : Gdx.files.internal("textures").list("png") ) {
        assetManager.load(f.toString(), Texture.class);
        System.out.println("Asset queued for loading: " + f.toString());
    }
    assetManager.finishLoading();
    System.out.println("Loaded assets: " + assetManager.getLoadedAssets());
```

This works fine when I run the desktop launcher, but it fails when I deploy it to html5 with the message:

```
GwtApplication: exception: Asset not loaded: textures/rifleman_walking.png
Asset not loaded: textures/rifleman_walking.png
```

I've doubledchecked the filenames, just to make sure there wasn't something as stupid as a typo on my end. I'm also a bit thrown off by the fact that it only seems to affect the html5 version. When I look at the assets/ directory in the project webroot, it does contain everything as referenced in the code.

Note that my code worked fine for both desktop and html5 before having `AssetManager` load textures, instead of loading the textures manually via hardcoded filenames.

**My theories:**

- Possibility 1: AssetManager fails to load textures for some reason.
- Possibility 2: AssetManager does not block while loading in html5

I got the exact same error for the exact same file when I forgot to include `assetManager.finishLoading();`, so I'm wondering if there's something special about the html5 deployment that requires a workaround.

---

Additionally, I have loads of debug info that I simply print via `System.out.println()`, and I would love to see this in the Gwt text area that now only prints the error upon start. How can I enable the output of `System.out.println()` in the same window?

After reading around, I found that calling `Gdx.app.setLogLevel(Application.LOG_INFO);` in the core launcher is the way to go, but it doesn't seem to change anything. If I was able to see what I print, it would help with the debugging a lot.

---

**Edit:**
The offending line is this:

```
protected Texture getAssetTexture(String textureName) {
    return world.getPainter().getAssetManager().get(textureName, Texture.class);
}
```

I've already checked that `textureName` is referenced correctly: The file `rifleman_walking.png` is residing in the `textures` subfolder of assets.

Comment: You say it works fine on desktop, but [`FileHandle#list(...)`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/files/FileHandle.html#list-java.lang.String-) does not work (reliable) on desktop, so that would explain why you think that "it works" on desktop. Also, you didn't include the stacktrace, so it's impossible to tell where the exception is thrown. Make sure to carefully read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Xoppa I have no idea how to see the stacktrace via Gwt. I only get the one error as listed, which is why I added that part at the end about debug output. Looking for alternative approaches to FileHandle.list, as a misbehaving call would correspond with my first theory.

Comment: I said that because the code you provided cannot throw that exception (you would need to call e.g. `AssetManager#get(...)` for that exception to be thrown). Which means that you didn't provide enough information to reproduce the problem you're having. Try it yourself: using only the information you provided in your question, can you actually reproduce the issue? Carefully read the link I referred to for more information on that.

Comment: @Xoppa Alright, I misunderstood what you first said. I clarified my code in the edit. It's 100% reproducable on html5, but works as intended on android.

Comment: Did you also read this page the article links to: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ? The code snippets you provided still don't provide enough information to reproduce the problem you're having. Btw, saying that you checked something doesn't mean it isn't needed to reproduce your problem. You want to make it those helping you as easy as possible: `copy | paste | run` is what you ultimately want to provide.

Comment: @Xoppa I think I found the source of the issue, and your first comment lead me on the right track: It would seem that `FileHandle`s `list()` doesn't work for directories in a linked `assets` folder. Will investigate further to confirm and try to produce a workaround tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, LibGDX pre-loads all assets before starting in HTML mode (because it's impossible to access images synchronously in JS otherwise). So my guess (without seeing the actual code) would be that you try to load assets before LibGDX is ready.

Don't get me started on System.out.println() in GWT. The simplest thing to see debug output is to call the corresponding LibGDX log function.